# Get last occurrence of date in PHP with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a dynamic block of plaintext in which there will always be at least one date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

For example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
>   blandit neque fringilla facilisis congue. Nunc sed libero nisi. Mauris
>   pretium magna non magna tincidunt, et cursus mi consectetur. Duis
>   varius augue vel ligula varius pretium.
>
> Suspendisse blandit justo nec maximus porta. Fusce egestas nisi purus,
>   at venenatis leo commodo tristique. Nam accumsan tellus lacus, a
>   fringilla nisl viverra sed. Aenean id eleifend ipsum, vel varius nunc.
>   In condimentum nisl eu arcu eleifend 1999-01-02 ultrices vel non
>   lacus.
>
> Vivamus a mauris id mauris vehicula sollicitudin. Suspendisse iaculis
>   ipsum sed metus sagittis dapibus.

How can I use regex to find the **last occurrence** of any date in that format and save it to a variable?

I presume there'll be a `preg_match()` involved.

The closest expression I can come up with is `\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d(?!.*\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)` which matches **any** date in that format.

Comment: So if it matches any date - take the __last one__.

Comment: You gotta use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Show us what you've tried instead of just guessing at how it should be done.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/MVsE1m/1)

```
.*\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

Uses `s` flag.

#### Usage

```
$re = '/.*\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/s';
$str = //your string here
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

---

### Explanation

- `.*` Match any character any number of times (greedy). Since the `s` flag is used it will also match `\n`.
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` The date format. You can prepend and append `\b` to ensure you don't match something like `12345-12-12` (5 numbers at the start) if you choose.